# Please provide me with a proof for the formula : $R(T) = \rho (1 + αT)$ which relates the change of resistivity with temperature

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Here, $\rho$ is the resistance at temperature ($T$) and ($R$) is the resistance at a given temperature. Also, will the value of $α$ become negative if the resistor is cooled?

Comment: What is $RT$ in this formula? - is it a single quantity or product of resistance and temperature (and then why $T(T)$???).

Comment: somebody edited this sorry, I just meant R as a function of T

Comment: Assume R as resistivity after increased temperature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation is just a generalization of an experimental fact that resistance is weakly dependent on temperature. Assuming that $R(T)$ is an unknown function,
we can expand
$$R(T)\approx R(T_0) + R'(T_0)(T-T_0) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{2}R''(T_0)(T-T_0)^2\right).$$
The last term is known experimentally to be small for most materials, which is why a good rule to use in not to extreme conditions is
$$ R(T)\approx R(T_0) + R'(T_0)(T-T_0) = R(T_0)\left[1 + \frac{R'(T_0)}{R(T_0)}(T-T_0)\right],$$
we can now define $\rho = R(T_0)$ and $\alpha =\frac{R'(T_0)}{R(T_0)}$ recovering the formula
$$R(T) = \rho\left[1+\alpha(T-T_0)\right].$$

**Update**
This is just one example of many *empirical laws* which are grounded in observations, but do not really have rigid status of the *laws if physics*. Most of them are justifiable to a good accuracy in linear regime.

To add more such examples:

- Ohm's law
- Relation $\mathbf{D}=\epsilon\mathbf{E}$
- Relation between the resistance and the cross-section and length of the wire: $R=\rho l/S$

The first two break already for non-linear macroscopic materials, and all three fail at nanoscale and/or in quantum regime.

An interesting counter example is the *laws of thermodynamics, which, although approximate, hold to a very high accuracy, determined by the number of molecules.

Comment: Oh, so it's all about a mathematical expansion and all this time I thought it was supposed to be profoundly conceptual....cool.                                                                                                                     Thank You.

Comment: @AtharvKapila Well there is a concept, the one that the resistivity is temperature dependent. How does rho depends on T is material specific and there are a lot of different possibilities, and we have found the relationship to good accuracy for many materials.

Comment: The point Vadim makes is that, regardless of rho vs T curve, it is always possible to find a small temperature region around T_0 where rho is roughly linear in T. Of course this does not apply near a superconducting critical temperature in a SC material.

Comment: I added some material to address several points raised in the comments.